# How to get data from lower nested function to the higher nested function?

Tags: javascript, nested, es6-promise

I have a problem to get data from lower nested function to the higher nested function, lets suppose required data is async I did try callbacks to no avail, promises do not give me proper result also - am I doing something wrong? I'm new in node.js environment.

Code:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] == '3'){
        function tfunc1(){
            function tfunc2(){
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    setTimeout(function(){ // lets suppose that there is some async work here
                        var tsomeData = 'TsomeData';
                        resolve(tsomeData);
                        reject(console.log('tfunc4 ERROR'));
                    }, 2000);
                });
            }
                    // promises:
                    tfunc2().then(function(tsomeData)
                    {
                        return afunc2(tsomeData);
                    }).then(function({tsomeData, asomeData})
                    {
                        return after(tsomeData, asomeData);
                    }).catch(function()
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
        }
    }

    if (array[i] == '6'){
        function afunc1(){
            function afunc2(tsomeData){
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    setTimeout(function(){ // lets suppose that there is some async work here
                        var asomeData = 'AsomeData';
                        resolve({tsomeData : tsomeData, asomeData : asomeData});
                        reject(console.log('afunc4 ERROR'));
                    }, 2000);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    // I need to work with tsomeData here - how to pass it here?
    // I need to work with asomeData here - how to pass it here?

    // tsomeData + asomeData mutating:
    function after(tsomeData, asomeData){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(function(){ // lets suppose that there is some async work here
                var newData = tsomeData + asomeData;
                resolve(console.log(newData));
                reject(console.log('after ERROR'));
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19bvo4vh/32)

Any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I have no idea what *exactly* you're trying to accomplish. The JSFiddle has quite a few mistakes and I have a hard time gauging the intentions.

There is however a way to simplify this by moving those functions outside of the loop and using the `Promise.all` functionality, like this. It's probably not entirely what you're expecting but I'm hoping it gives you something to go by:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var array_length = array.length;
var promises = [];
console.clear();


function tfunc1() {
  promises.push(tfunc2());
}

function afunc1() {
  promises.push(afunc2());
}

function tfunc2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(time => resolve('Tsomedata'), 2000);
  });
}

function afunc2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(time => resolve('Asomedata'), 1000);
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
  switch (array[i]) {
    case 3:
      tfunc1();
      break;
    case 6:
      afunc1();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
  //both Tsomedata and Asomedata are available in the `data` array.
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful I will try to implement this specific route and see if it's going to work.